# Zoom integration with Web apps using Iframe (Meeting SDK)

Tags: zoom-sdk

I worked as per the best practice guide to integrate Zoom Meeting SDK with Web app using Iframe and it is working fine. However, I have few problems which I was not able to figure it out.

Best practice guide:
https://developers.zoom.us/blog/meeting-sdk-iframe/

I have created **div** in the Iframe (with some fixed % width and height) and passed this **div** onload() function of the html mentioned in Iframe. I could able to get the zoom content in the **div**.

The problem here is, when I switch to various views like Gallery view and Speaker view, the size of the zoom content div is changing as per the selected view.

On such changes, I am not able to set the same dimensions to the parent Iframe, because of which, some part of the zoom div content is hidden within the Iframe.

Is there a way to get the dimension of the zoom content div on change, so that I can update the same dimensions to parent Iframe dynamically.

I believe this should be common problem with many users.

Regards
Harish Alwala